# Solving for Optimal Linear Isometry

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, unitary-matrices

**Updated:**

Let $X,Y$ be matrices in $Mat_{d\times D}(\mathbb{R})$. and fix $\lambda >0$  How can I find a pair of matrices $A,B$ such that:
$$
\min_{\underset{A \in Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R}) \, A^{\top}A =I_d}{B \in Mat_{d\times D}(\mathbb{R})}}\|A(X-B) -Y\|_F + \lambda \|B\|_F
$$
where $Mat_{d\times D}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $d\times D$ matrices with real-coefficients and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

How can we solve for $A$?  I looked it up, *and by a comment below*, if we additionally constrain $B=0$ then the solution is
$$
A =  U^{\top}V \mbox{ where $U\Sigma V^{\top}$ is the SVD of A}.
$$
But what about in general?

Comment: Why skew-symmetric? Is there any assumption on $A$?

Comment: Oh but isn't the tangent space of the set of Orthogonal matrices the set of skew-symmetric matrices?  (Also there is no other assumptions on A).

Comment: There is no mentioning of orthogonal matrices in the post either. Please include all important information on $A$.

Comment: short answer: do an svd, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Comment: @user619894 Thank you, I modifier the post accordingly to seek affine isometries instead of linear isometries only.

Comment: Let $C=(-AB),\,$ then you are asking about a least-squares solution of
$\,Y=(AX+C)\;$ given $\,(X,Y).\,$ But there are an infinite number of solutions for the $(A,C)$ matrices. Some kind of criteria/constraint is needed to distinguish one of them as optimal.

Comment: Fair enough, I added a Frobenius regularization term on $B$ then.

Comment: Since $A$ is orthogonal, I believe $\|B\|=\|AB\|$ so you can replace $AB$ with $B$

Comment: Interesting, though I'm curious how would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing convenience, use a colon as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A$$
Then define the matrix $Z=X-B\,$ and assume for the moment that $B$,
and therefore $Z$, are fixed.

Expand the objective function as
$$\eqalign{
\|AZ-Y\|_F^2
  &= (AZ-Y):(AZ-Y) \\
   &= AZ:AZ + Y:Y - 2Y:AZ \\
   &= (A^TA:ZZ^T + Y:Y) - 2YZ^T:A 
&\qquad\big\{ A^TA=I\big\} \\
   &= (I:ZZ^T + Y:Y) - UDV^T:A
&\qquad\big\{ {\rm SVD\,factorization}\big\} \\
   &= \Big(\|Z\|^2_F+\|Y\|^2_F\Big) - {\rm Tr}(D\,U^TAV) \\
}$$
This leads to the standard Procrustes solution method:
$$\eqalign{
\min_A\,\|AZ-Y\|_F^2
 \quad\implies\quad \max_A\,{\rm Tr}(D\,U^TAV) 
 \quad\implies\quad A=UV^T 
}$$
However, $B$ is not fixed so we're free to choose it to minimize the objective function.

Setting $B=X-Y\;$ yields
$$\eqalign{
Z=Y,\quad A=I \quad\implies\quad \|AZ-Y\|_F^2=0
}$$
which is the global minimum for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Are you saying that the result is independent of $\lambda$?